# How can you change the zoom shortcut keys in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

The shortcuts for zooming in and out in Notepad++ require using a mousewheel or a number pad, neither of which can be found on most laptops (like mine).

You can change the shortcut keys by the menu option `Settings`>`Shortcut Mapper`, but the zoom features don't show up on this list.

How can I change the zoom shortcut keys to something else?  (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, for example.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Zoom commands are mapped in the **Scintilla commands** section.

Using the menu option `Settings -> Shortcut Mapper...` go to the `Scintilla Commands` tab and you can change the mapping there:

[image: Scintilla commands]

Comment: To get to this view, `Macro` -> `Modify Shrotcut/Delete Macro`

Comment: Or Settings->Shortcut mapper.